# Firefox debian - server not found only for some addresses but ok with other browsers

Tags: linux, firefox, debian

EDIT 1: when activating DNS over HTTPS option in firefox settings, everything is working again. Can firefox mess-up something in classic resolution only for some addresses?

Machine under debian testing, updated today.

I have a strange behavior from my firefox, some websites, and only a few, can't load correctly. IE with linkedin, the page is displayed without CSS and almost no content. In the firefox console I have

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/bpob6bbc8gauqn4cct96xaqpf”. www.linkedin.com:1932:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/efncoxjdl37tofw662sg013tp”.
```

And the fact, when I try loading one of those addresses, I have a "Server not found".

Everything is working fine under chrome or even Tor (which is in the end a modified firefox).

```
dig static-exp1.licdn.com
```

is returning correct entries
my DNS configuration is correct (tried with multiple servers)
I have nothing in my host file and no firewall/security rules/softwares in place

This problem occurs with firefox ESR installed from debian repositories and firefox downloaded from mozilla website. No add-ons installed.

Things I tried:

- remove firefox+config/profile and fresh reinstall.
- disable DNS prefetch and IPV6 in firefox config.
- reinstall all package dependencies with apt.
- update-ca-certificates

Timezone date/time is configured correctly and sync with NTP

Thanks if you have any tips to sort this out.